# Get date in mysql recursive 'x' week

Tags: mysql

I have got the query which will give me all the dates which are Monday and Tuesday

```
SELECT a.Date AS dat_e FROM ( SELECT DATE_ADD( '2018-01-17' , INTERVAL (1) DAY ) + INTERVAL( a.a + ( 10 * b.a ) + ( 100 * c.a ) ) DAY AS DATE FROM ( SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 ) AS a CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 ) AS b CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 ) AS c )a HAVING  DAYOFWEEK(dat_e) IN ( 2,3)
```

I want to get the dates after 'x' weeks, ie: after 1,2 or 3 weeks. and the dates should be Monday and Tuesday

Comment: after 1,2 or 3 weeks of a month?

Comment: yes, from the date specified

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You're aware that sql is for the storage and retrieval of data, right?